# Android Studio App logging

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, android-sharedpreferences

I need to store as many users and password as I need, but in my code only store the last user. here I am only logging with the last user and the past were deleted as overwrite:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConstraintLayout cl1,cl2;
    CheckBox chk;
    EditText usr,pass,nusr,nreg;
    Button btnReg, btnIng,btnNewReg;
    SharedPreferences shared;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cl1=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.cl1);
        cl2=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.cl2);
        chk= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk);
        usr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        nusr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.RegNobre);
        nreg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Regpass);
        cl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        shared=getSharedPreferences("datos",MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void registrar(View view) {
        cl1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        cl2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I think from here is the modification but I dont know:

```
public void newregistro(View view) {
    if (chk.isChecked()){
        cl1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editor=shared.edit();
        editor.putString("Nombre",nusr.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("pass",nreg.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }

    else mensaje("No olvide aceptar las politicas");
}

public void mensaje(String s){
    Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void ingresar(View view) {
    String usrShar=shared.getString("Nombre","");
    String passShar=shared.getString("pass","");
    if (usr.getText().toString().equals(usrShar))
        if (pass.getText().toString().equals(passShar))
            mensaje("datos ok");
        else mensaje("verifique sus datos o registrese");
    else mensaje("verifique sus dato o registrese");
}
```

Comment: use a list to store passwords in shared prefs. Whenever new user log in with new password then update in the saved list and save it again

Comment: how i implement that?

Comment: Just create a list of object having name and password and save to shared preference. Then everytime you just neeg to add new password to that list and update in shared preference.

Comment: Remember that you first get the list and add new values to it then save it back

Answer (score 1):

The keys must to be unique

editor.putString("Nombre1",nusr.getText().toString());
editor.putString("pass1",nreg.getText().toString());

editor.putString("Nombre2",nusr.getText().toString());
editor.putString("pass2",nreg.getText().toString());

Comment: This is a dirty implementation. There are many good ways to achieve the behaviour that OP has asked.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the previous user and password will be overwritten as you are just storing the user name and password under the same key in your `SharedPreference` which is replacing the previous one. To store all the user name and password, I suggest you to store all the user name and password in a sqlite database table.

For storing all the user name and password that you enter in your application, using `SharedPreference` is not a good idea. Here's a [nice tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android) on how you store and retrieve the data from sqlite table.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set (Collection type) to store the user and password ,In your case you are storing the user and password using the same key in shared preferences, I've updated your code. Check it out.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ConstraintLayout cl1,cl2;
CheckBox chk;
EditText usr,pass,nusr,nreg;
Button btnReg, btnIng,btnNewReg;
SharedPreferences shared;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Set users_passwords; //create a set instance


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cl1=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.cl1);
    cl2=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.cl2);
    chk= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk);
    usr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    nusr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.RegNobre);
    nreg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Regpass);
    cl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    shared=getSharedPreferences("datos",MODE_PRIVATE);

    users_passwords = new HashSet(); //create a set object

}

public void registrar(View view) {
    cl1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cl2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}}
```

Add password and user to the set object

```
 public void newregistro(View view) {
    if (chk.isChecked()){


        cl1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //First you need to get the previous object to append the new user and password
    users_passwords = shared.getStringSet("users",null); 

        editor=shared.edit();
        users_passwords.add(nusr.getText().toString());
        users_passwords.add(nreg.getText().toString());
        editor.putStringSet("users",users_passwords);
        editor.commit();
    }

    else mensaje("No olvide aceptar las politicas");
}

    public void ingresar(View view) {
        users_passwords = shared.getStringSet("users",null);

        if (users_passwords.contains(usr.getText().toString()))
            if (users_passwords.contains(pass.getText().toString()))
                mensaje("datos ok");
            else mensaje("verifique sus datos o registrese");
        else mensaje("verifique sus dato o registrese");
    }
```